# Passing threadCount to surefire plugin from maven cmdline

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

I have in my pom the following settings for maven surefire plugin.
Occasionally I might want to run the tests with less threads. I was hoping for a way to set it from the mvn command line.

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.0</version>
         <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                     <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                     <version>2.22.0</version>
                </dependency>
         </dependencies>
         <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                <includes>
                         <include>com.Online.runner.Regression.ONLINE_Chrome_RunnerTest</include>
                </includes>
         </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I attempt to use the command below it doesn't appear to work.

```
mvn clean test -X -DthreadCount=1
```

Checking the values through the debugger shows that has set a system property. But it seems to get ignored.

```
[DEBUG] Setting system property [threadCount]=[1]
[DEBUG] parallel='methods', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=5,
```

My tests still run in parallel. What am I doing wrong? there must be a way to override this value in the Pom?

EDIT: It seems as though it is completely ignoring the threadCount value altogether even the one set in the POM. Is this value not passed to the dependency Junit47?

Comment: First why have you defined a plugin dependency surefire-junit47 which is not needed...Apart from that I recommend to read the docs http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html and why do you need to change this configuration via command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise Not sure why that plugin was included. But as this is a project I have inherited I didn't want to get rid of it just in case. Although if you think that might be an issue I will remove it. I am deploying the build from a cloud tool and might not always have the capacity for this number of threads. So instead of recoding the branch and pom each time, it would be easier to set it as a variable at runtime.

Comment: @khmarbaise It looks like that dependency was defined to force surefire plugin to launch with Junit instead of testng. Looks like at some point this project changed testing frameworks. Less than ideal

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to work, remove it with pom.xml:

`<threadCount> 5 </threadCount>`

Maven startup line:

`mvn test -DthreadCount=5`